# Is there any way to add custom R-function action to a button in DT?

Tags: r, datatables, dt

I'm trying to add a custom button performing the action defined by R-function to my datatable. I've used the same list of options in my R code as in Javascript code in [Datatables manual](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/custom.html), but it doesn't work.

Here is a code from [Datatables manual](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/custom.html):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'My button',
                action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                alert( 'Button activated' );
                }
            }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

And here is my code in R:

```
require(DT)
DT::datatable(iris,
    extensions = 'Buttons',
    options = list(
        dom = 'Bfrtip',
        buttons = list(
            list(
                text = 'test',
                action = print('1')
                )
        )
    )
)
```

Executing it I've received an error:

```
Error in if (extend != "collection") extend else listButtons(cfg) : 
  argument is of length zero
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set `extend = "collection"`, like this:

```
library(DT)
datatable(iris,
          extensions = 'Buttons',
          options = list(
            dom = 'Bfrtip',
            buttons = list(
              "copy",
              list(
                extend = "collection",
                text = 'test',
                action = DT::JS("function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                                    alert( 'Button activated' );
                                }")
              )
            )
          )
)
```

But the action can only execute some Javascript, not a R command. However you can execute a R command by clicking a custom button if you put the datatable in a shiny application. Something like that:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- basicPage(
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$dtable <- renderDT(
    datatable(iris,
              extensions = 'Buttons',
              options = list(
                dom = 'Bfrtip',
                buttons = list(
                  "copy",
                  list(
                    extend = "collection",
                    text = 'test',
                    action = DT::JS("function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                                      Shiny.setInputValue('test', true);
                                   }")
                  )
                )
              )
    )
  )

  observeEvent(input$test, {
    if(input$test){
      print("hello")
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: That works, but I’ve changed your code slightly in order to use the button as a trigger. So I’ve added `priority: "event"` option as it was described in the section 'Values vs. Events' of [this Shiny manual page](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicating-with-js.html).

Comment: Could you clarify why did you use `if(input$test)`? The code works fine for me without it.

Comment: @asvx You're right, the `if` is useless. And you're right to use `priority: "event"`. I didn't know `priority: "event"`, I used a trick before to trigger the input change when the value does not change, but using `priority: "event"` is definitely better. Thanks.